# sometimes occurs "tesseract is not installed or it is not in your path"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using tesseract in while loop in my script. But from time to time (once daily) I am getting this error. Tesseract is installed and works, but I get this message once per day. How to solve it?

```
Traceback:
File file.py, line 169, in <module> results.append(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py, line 286, in image_to_string
return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
File /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py, line 201, in run_and_get_output
   raise TesseractNotFoundError()
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path
```

version:

```
tesseract 3.04.01
 leptonica-1.74.1
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 6b (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.1) : libpng 1.6.28 : libtiff 4.0.8 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.5.2 : libopenjp2 2.1.2
```

tesseract works once I start my script, but suddenly (usually once daily, sometimes second day) tesseract returns "tesseract is not installed or it's not in your path". When I start script again, then it works correctly again.

What is wrong with it?